# I don't get why the square roots of the probabilities should transform linearly

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, linear-systems

I do get why probability should transform linearly. Consider (in classical mechanics), a system whose state is unknown to us, and is given by a probability vector $(0.3,0.2,0.5)$ where the numbers are the probabilities that the state is some known state in the phase space, $$|x_1,p_1\rangle, |x_2,p_2\rangle, |x_3,p_3\rangle.$$ So, to get the probability vector at a later time, we can evolve these three phase space points according to Hamilton's equations, and then produce the linear combination: $$0.3 |x'_1,p'_1\rangle, +0.2|x'_2,p'_2\rangle+0.5|x'_3,p'_3\rangle.$$

So we've established that probability vectors transform linearly. However, the complex wave-function is the square root of the probability vector (at least, the magnitudes of its components are square roots of the respective components of the probability vector).

Given that the probability vector transforms linearly, how come its square root also transforms linearly, as square root is a non-linear operation? Granted, my above example only holds in classical mechanics. But, the square-root wave function even exists in classical mechanics as this article shows in the definitions section:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopman%E2%80%93von_Neumann_classical_mechanics

Comment: The probabilities in classical mechanics do not transform in the same way asin quantum mechanics. It is necessary to distinguish the probability theory and physical theory.

Comment: @RogerVadim But the square-root wave-function even exists in classical mechanics, and it transforms linearly! That's what's in the link. How can something as well as its square root transform linearly?

Comment: do you see a contradiction in their derivation? Perhaps, you should be more specific about it in your question.

Comment: @RogerVadim I didn't really understand their derivation. It has a remark which says it only works because there are first order differential operators. Besides, how can something as well as its square root transform linearly, when square root itself is non linear? That's what I made this post about. Looking for an intuitive explanation instead of just math

Comment: @RogerVadim There's a reason they introduced the complex conjugate, instead of just a usual square root. What is that reason? I suppose complex numbers somehow make work what square roots alone can't.

Comment: Well done on posting an answer to your own question. [That's very much encouraged](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). You may also enjoy [Scott Aaronson's discussion](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html) of what goes wrong with some obvious alternatives to how probability works in quantum mechanics, no-squaring included. (He also has a [possibly more heavy-going](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/island.pdf) paper on the same subject.)

Comment: @J.G. Thanks. I was looking for that. I was trying to read a similar paper but it wasn't as well-explained as this. But I do hope physics never gets all computer-sciency. Discrete stuff is so ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. Consider (in classical mechanics), an initial state which is $a|x_1,p_1\rangle+b|x_2,p_2\rangle$, such that $a+b=1$.

Suppose, at a later time $t$, both these states evolve (superimpose) into the same state $|x_3, p_3\rangle$, as given by Hamilton's equations.

Now, working out the math in the "square root wave-function" formulation should give us the same prediction, i.e. the final state $|x_3,p_3\rangle$ with probability 1. So let's work out the math.

In the "square-root wave function formulation, the initial state is $\sqrt{a} |x_1 \rangle + \sqrt{b} |x_2 \rangle$. Let's evolve these two component states indivudally and then superimpose the results.

Let's say, evolving $\sqrt{a} |x_1,p_1\rangle$ gives us $\sqrt{a} e^{im} |x_3,p_3 \rangle$ after time $t$. Evolving $\sqrt{b} |x_2, p_2 \rangle$ gives $\sqrt{b} e^{in} |x_3,p_3 \rangle$.

Superimposing gives:

$$\sqrt{a} e^{im} +\sqrt{b} e^{in} |x_3,p_3 \rangle$$

as the final state

Its modulus squared is:

$$a+b+2ab \cos{\theta}$$

$$=1+ 2ab\cos{\theta}$$

For this to be 1, as predicted by the other formulation at the top, $\cos{\theta}$ must be 0. This must be like some sort of restriction that classical mechanics puts on $\theta$? If this restriction is lifted, the probabilities can even cancel each other out, like what happens in quantum mechanics.

Also, all this wouldn't work without complex states. Just doing square root is insufficient.